# Remove fraction from matlab graph

Tags: matlab

I have drawn a graph no. of people vs salary. In the graph no. of face has fraction points 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5. But the no. of people cannot be float point. Is it possible to draw graph where only discrete value of no. of face is visible. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify the `XTick` property of your axis manually, once the plotting process has been performed, as follows:

```
plot(...);
set(gca,'XTick',1:5);
```

For more information about how to handle axis tick values, read [this](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html).